# Async JS - function in waterfall not executing callback properly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I am trying to get back to values from the function getFeed(), feedItems and feedMeta. I receive the following:

```
/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:228
    return supportsSymbol && fn[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction';
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined
    at isAsync (/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:228:32)
    at wrapAsync (/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:232:12)
    at /Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3866:9
    at replenish (/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:17)
    at /Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1002:9
    at eachOfLimit (/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1027:24)
    at /Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1032:16
    at _parallel (/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3865:5)
    at Object.series (/Users/react-backend/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4721:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/react-backend/feedParser2.js:114:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:10)
```

in the console when using the code immediately below:

```
function getFeed(callback) {
    let req = request(urlTestFeed);
    let feedparser = new FeedParser(feedParserOptions);
    let feedItems = [];
    let feedMeta = null;

    req.on('response', function(response) {
        let stream = this;
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            stream.pipe(feedparser);
        }
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
    });

    feedparser.on('meta', function() {
        try {
            feedMeta = this.meta;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
        }
    });

    feedparser.on('readable', function() {
        try {
            let item = this.read();
            if (item !== null) {
                feedItems.push(item);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
        }
    });

    feedparser.on('end', function() {
        callback(undefined, feedItems, feedMeta);
    });

    feedparser.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
        callback(err);
    });
}
```

async:

```
async.waterfall([
        getFeed(function(err, feedItems, feedMeta) {
            console.log(feedMeta)
            if (!err) {
                if (feedMeta.title && feedMeta.description && feedMeta.link) {

                }
            }
        })]);
```

If I add `callback(undefined, feedItems, feedMeta);` to the last line in getFeed:

```
function getFeed(callback) {
    let req = request(urlTestFeed);
    let feedparser = new FeedParser(feedParserOptions);
    let feedItems = [];
    let feedMeta = null;

    req.on('response', function(response) {
        let stream = this;
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            stream.pipe(feedparser);
        }
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
    });

    feedparser.on('meta', function() {
        try {
            feedMeta = this.meta;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
        }
    });

    feedparser.on('readable', function() {
        try {
            let item = this.read();
            if (item !== null) {
                feedItems.push(item);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
        }
    });

    feedparser.on('end', function() {
        callback(undefined, feedItems, feedMeta);
    });

    feedparser.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('getFeed: err.message == ' + err.message);
        callback(err);
    });
    callback(undefined, feedItems, feedMeta);
}
```

I get the following in the console:

```
null
/Users/react-backend/feedParser2.js:119
            if (feedMeta.title && feedMeta.description && feedMeta.link) {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
```

What happened to the value of feedMeta when I added the callback? How can I pass the values from feedparser,feeditems, and, err to Async.waterfall?

Comment: I think getFeed is not executing.

Comment: getFeed wasn't executing because of the parameters I was sending it in the async call. Please delete this post, mods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing this is too little, too late - but the problem isn't that getFeed isn't executing (it is actually executing - but you're returning before you get the results back from trying to read from a URL).  The issue is that you're mixing asynchronous patterns with synchronous patterns.

I'd recommend simplifying what you're trying to do before moving this into async waterfall.

Specifically, gut the contents of your readFeed to be this:

```
function getFeed(callback){
    console.log('getFeed');
    return callback(null, [], {});
}
```

Then call it using the following

```
async.waterfall([
    function first (next){
        getFeed(function(err, feedItems, feedMeta) {
            console.log('getFeed cb:', feedMeta);
            if (!err) {
                if (feedMeta.title && feedMeta.description && feedMeta.link) {

                }
            }
            return next(err);
        })        
    }
],
function(err){
    console.log('waterfall done: err:',err);
});
```

Here is an example of the "flow of waterfall" (i.e. more than a single function being given to the waterfall):

```
async.waterfall([
    function first (next){
        getFeed(function(err, feedItems, feedMeta) {
            console.log('getFeed cb:', feedMeta);
            if (!err) {
                if (feedMeta.title && feedMeta.description && feedMeta.link) {

                }
            }
            return next(null, "rando");        
        })
    },
    function second(input, next){
        console.log('second: input:', input);
        return next('something bad happened');
    }
],
function(err){
    console.log('waterfall done: err:',err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still working on it, actually. Is next a name for the data being passed to the next function in the waterfall?

Comment: "next" can be named anything - it is just the callback for progressing the waterfall.  Once your series (array of functions to waterfall) completes - the final callback is called (where the "waterfall done" log is located).

Technically if you had multiple functions in your waterfall - the return from each of your waterfall functions is fed to each subsequent function.  Comments aren't great for code - can show in another answer.

Comment: I've got it now. Thanks!